# Making custom field appear in captions for image attachments (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm a designer (not a developer) working on a Wordpress site for a customer. Using the [ACF-plugin](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) I've set up a custom field on media files for photo credits. This works fine on featured images, where I can call it in single.php like this:

```
$post_thumbnail = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id());
$credit = get_field('media_credit', $post_thumbnail);
if($credit):
echo '<div class="media-credit"><p>Photo: '.$credit.'</p></div>';
endif;
```

So I know the custom field works, and outputs the right data. However, I can't get it to work on image attachments in posts. What I have is this:

```
add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode', 'my_img_caption_shortcode', 10, 3 );

function my_img_caption_shortcode( $empty, $attr, $content ){
    $attr = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id'      => '',
        'align'   => 'alignnone',
        'width'   => '',
        'caption' => ''
    ), $attr );

    if ( 1 > (int) $attr['width'] || empty( $attr['caption'] ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    if ( $attr['id'] ) {
        $attr['id'] = 'id="' . esc_attr( $attr['id'] ) . '" ';
    }
    //OUTPUT CREDIT
    $photographer = get_field( 'media_credit', $attachment_id );
    if ($photographer):$media_byline = '<br/><span class="media-credit">Photo: '.$photographer.'</span>';endif;

    return '<div ' . $attr['id']
    . 'class="wp-caption ' . esc_attr( $attr['align'] ) . '" '
    . do_shortcode( $content )
    . '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . $attr['caption'] . '' . $media_byline . '</p>'
    . '</div>';

}
```

If I remove the if-statement in OUTPUT it shows «Photo: » within the captions, after the text like it should, but it doesn't get any data. What am I missing?

(BTW – I know there are plugins that outputs image credits, but they tend to have styles and features I have to override, resulting in a spaghetti mess I'd hate to hand over to the next guy working on this site.)

Comment: what do you get here :   $photographer = get_field( 'media_credit', $attachment_id );

Comment: you can get all the attached attachments from the post id and then from the attachment id you get your custom meta field data. Please check from URL to get the attachments, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179856/how-do-you-get-all-the-urls-of-images-attached-to-a-post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this to work! :-D Instead of using `$attachment_id`, I got the ID from `$attr`, and then stripped the 'attachment_' prefix from output.

I also made separate fields for photographer and bureau, but I guess that's beside the point.

Here is the code:

```
function my_img_caption_shortcode( $empty, $attr, $content ){
    $attr = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id'      => '',
        'align'   => 'alignnone',
        'width'   => '',
        'caption' => ''
    ), $attr );

    if ( 1 > (int) $attr['width'] || empty( $attr['caption'] ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    $credit_id = $attr['id'];
    $credit_id = str_replace( 'attachment_', '', $credit_id );

    $photographer = get_field( 'media_credit', $credit_id );
    $bureau_credit = get_field( 'media_bureau', $credit_id );
    if ( $photographer && $bureau_credit ): $dash = ' / ';
    endif;
    if ( $photographer || $bureau_credit ): $media_byline = '<br/><span class="media-credit">PHOTO: '
        . $photographer . ''
        . $dash . '<span class="bureau-credit">'
        . $bureau_credit
        . '</span></span>';
    endif;

    return '<div id="attachment_' . $credit_id . '"'
    . 'class="wp-caption ' . esc_attr( $attr['align'] ) . '" '
    . do_shortcode( $content )
    . '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . $attr['caption'] . '' . $media_byline . '</p>'
    . '</div>';
}

add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode', 'my_img_caption_shortcode', 10, 3 );
```

This solution is something I lifted from the [AFC Media Credit-plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-media-credit/), so credits to the developer.

I hope this is useful for anybody who wants to achieve something similar.